# When a group of people (a community / a society or even a nation) always see the negative side of a matter

Tags: phrase-choice, idiomatic-language

Please imagine there is a group of people, a community, a society or even a nation of a country who do not think in an proper and acceptable manner and always think about evil things and as the saying goes they just see the negative part of everything.

For example they see a young couple and have no idea who they are and what they are going to do and they have no idea about their relationship. However they judge them and their relationship in the worst manner. What is the best way to describe such a quality? Do the following self-made sentences work in natural English?

> - Their thoughts are poisoned.
> - Their thoughts are ill / sick / patient.

If not, then please let me know how shall I indicate the above sentences in a manner it could seem natural?

Answer (score 1):

**Their thoughts are poisonous** sounds okay.

You could say **their thoughts are rotten**.

*Their thoughts are ill / sick / patient* is not a good construction.

You could simply say **They always think the worst of people**.